# .animate in if statement

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate, anchor

I'm a begginer in jQuery and I try to develop a script for my menu.
The statement is the following :
- I have a vertical menu
- I have a submenu that moves (changing margin-top value) in function of the user position into the page (tracking his scroll activity)
- This submenu is settle behind the links in the menu and change of background in function of the user position in the page

The problem is: I tried to use the .animate() function to change the position of the submenu and create a smooth effect in jQuery but it doesn't work in my if statement. Here is my code :

**The HTML :**

```
<div id="menu"> 

        <div id="logo">
            <h1>NAME OF THE COMPANY</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="sub_menu">
            <div id="sub_menu_left">
                <div class="selecteur_left" id="selecteur_left_presentation">
                    <div class="selecteur_icon">
                        <i class="icon-user"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="selecteur_right" id="selecteur_right_presentation">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sub_menu_right">
                <div id="presentation_menu">
                </div>
                <div id="tests_menu">
                </div>
                <div id="entrainements_menu">
                </div>
                <div id="tarifs_menu">
                </div>
                <div id="contact_menu">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul>                
            <hr>
            <li>
                <a href="#presentation" id="presentation_link" class="smoothScroll">
                    <span>PRÉSENTATION</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <hr>
            <li>
                <a href="#tests" id="tests_link" class="smoothScroll">
                    <span>TESTS</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <hr>
            <li>
                <a href="#entrainements" id="entrainements_link" class="smoothScroll">
                    <span id="entrainement_title_menu">ENTRAÎNEMENT</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <hr>
            <li>
                <a href="#tarifs" id="tarifs_link" class="smoothScroll">
                    <span>TARIFS</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <hr>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" id="contact_link" class="smoothScroll">
                    <span>CONTACT</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <hr>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

My menu is split into 3 categories :
- The logo
- The submenu (wich moove when I arrive in the different anchors in the page)
- The li which are my links

And here is my script.

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
var scrollTotal;
            var height_1 = $('#presentation').outerHeight();
            var height_2 = $('#presentation').outerHeight() + $('#tests').outerHeight();
            var height_3 = $('#presentation').outerHeight() + $('#tests').outerHeight() + $('#entrainements').outerHeight();
            var height_4 = $('#presentation').outerHeight() + $('#tests').outerHeight() + $('#entrainements').outerHeight() + $('#tarifs').outerHeight();
            var height_5 = $('#presentation').outerHeight() + $('#tests').outerHeight() + $('#entrainements').outerHeight() + $('#tarifs').outerHeight() + $('#contact').outerHeight();

            $(window).scroll(function(){

                scrollTotal = $(window).scrollTop();

                if(scrollTotal <= height_1){
                    $("#sub_menu_left, #sub_menu_right").animate({ 
                        marginTop: "10px",
                    }, 10 );
                    $('i').removeClass();
                    $('i').addClass('icon-user');
                    $('#presentation_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '1'
                    });
                    $('#tests_menu , #entrainements_menu , #tarifs_menu , #contact_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '0'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_left_presentation').css({
                        'background-color' : '#34405A'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_right_presentation').css({
                        'border-left-color' : '#34405A'
                    });
                    $('.selecteur_icon').css({
                        'background-color' : '#181d2a'
                    });
                    $('#entrainement_title_menu').css({
                        'color' : 'white'
                    });
                    $('#logo').css({
                        'border-color' : '#34405A'
                    })
                } else if(height_1 < scrollTotal && scrollTotal <= height_2){
                    $("#sub_menu_left, #sub_menu_right").animate({ 
                        marginTop: "72px",
                    }, 10 );
                    $('i').removeClass();
                    $('i').addClass('icon-check');
                    $('#tests_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '1'
                    });
                    $('#presentation_menu , #entrainements_menu , #tarifs_menu , #contact_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '0'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_left_presentation').css({
                        'background-color' : '#586E9A'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_right_presentation').css({
                        'border-left-color' : '#586E9A'
                    });
                    $('.selecteur_icon').css({
                        'background-color' : '#3a4a69'
                    });
                    $('#entrainement_title_menu').css({
                        'color' : 'white'
                    });
                    $('#logo').css({
                        'border-color' : '#586E9A'
                    })
                } else if(height_2 < scrollTotal && scrollTotal <= height_3){
                    $("#sub_menu_left, #sub_menu_right").animate({ 
                        marginTop: "133px",
                    }, 10 );
                    $('i').removeClass();
                    $('i').addClass('icon-sort-by-attributes');
                    $('#entrainements_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '1'
                    });
                    $('#presentation_menu , #tests_menu , #tarifs_menu , #contact_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '0'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_left_presentation').css({
                        'background-color' : '#FDF5F1'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_right_presentation').css({
                        'border-left-color' : '#FDF5F1'
                    });
                    $('.selecteur_icon').css({
                        'background-color' : '#949494'
                    });
                    $('#entrainement_title_menu').css({
                        'color' : '#949494'
                    });
                    $('#logo').css({
                        'border-color' : '#FDF5F1'
                    })
                } else if(height_3 < scrollTotal && scrollTotal <= height_4){
                    $("#sub_menu_left, #sub_menu_right").animate({ 
                        marginTop: "194px",
                    }, 10 );
                    $('i').removeClass();
                    $('i').addClass('icon-eur');
                    $('#tarifs_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '1'
                    });
                    $('#presentation_menu , #tests_menu , #entrainements_menu , #contact_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '0'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_left_presentation').css({
                        'background-color' : '#7C94AC'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_right_presentation').css({
                        'border-left-color' : '#7C94AC'
                    });
                    $('.selecteur_icon').css({
                        'background-color' : '#546679'
                    });
                    $('#entrainement_title_menu').css({
                        'color' : 'white'
                    });
                    $('#logo').css({
                        'border-color' : '#7C94AC'
                    })
                } else if(scrollTotal > height_4){
                    $("#sub_menu_left, #sub_menu_right").animate({ 
                        marginTop: "255px",
                    }, 10 );
                    $('i').removeClass();
                    $('i').addClass('icon-envelope ');
                    $('#contact_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '1'
                    });
                    $('#presentation_menu , #tests_menu , #entrainements_menu , #tarifs_menu').css({
                        'opacity' : '0'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_left_presentation').css({
                        'background-color' : '#D55C41'
                    });
                    $('#selecteur_right_presentation').css({
                        'border-left-color' : '#D55C41'
                    });
                    $('.selecteur_icon').css({
                        'background-color' : '#964735'
                    });
                    $('#entrainement_title_menu').css({
                        'color' : 'white'
                    });
                    $('#logo').css({
                        'border-color' : '#D55C41'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

I wanted to track the height of my different categories and move the submenu (with the margin-top propriety) in function of the current height in the page. Everything work except the animate function (it works but it's not animate). If I change the value of the time (10ms to 100 or 1000), it never mooves.

I'm aware that my script can be symplify but first of all I want to see if it could work.
Anyone have a solution for that?
Regards.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `"margin-top"` and then don't put a comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately, it doesn't work neither...

Comment: Maybe try making them relative or absolute positions and change `top` attribute.  Create a jsfiddle and try duplicating it on a small scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running this function every time the user scrolls then you'll be trying to animate the position every time, which could reset the animation queue.  Try filtering out elements that are in the progress of animating:

```
// remove matched elements that are in the process of animating:
$("#sub_menu_left, #sub_menu_right").filter(':not(:animated)').animate( ..... )
```